# P tag replaced with H2 in about me section

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

I noticed that the P tag in about me section has been replaced recently with H2 tag in Stack Overflow only. For other sites, it's still P tag.

### Stack Overflow

[image: Inspect element showing h2 tag.]

### Travel.SE

[image: Inspect element showing p tag.]

As a temporary workaround, starting about me with a closing `h2` currently fixes the problem.

[image]

Comment: You need to surround the `<hr>`s with blank lines on each side. It’s the `---` in your Markdown. If there are no blank lines above, the line above will be interpreted as a heading.

Comment: See [Heading underline markdown rendering differently in preview to published](/q/401012/4642212) and [Inconsistency between preview and actual snippet when adding quotes](/q/400831/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no bug here. Your Stack Overflow profile contains extra lines that your other profiles don’t have, and those extra lines have specific meaning in Markdown formatting.

The second line in your profile text consists of 3 dashes:

```
First line
---
<br><br><br><br>
```

These dashes combine with the line of text immediately above it, and it is this *combination* that is creating the header.

This syntax is called a [*setext heading*](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#setext-headings) in the CommonMark specification; putting dashes directly under a line of text turns that line into an H2 header:

> ### First line

Had you used `=` equals signs instead of `-` dashes you’d have created an H1 header.

If you meant to use the dashes to denote a horizontal ruler (`<hr>`), you need to have a blank line in between:

```
First line

---
<br><br><br><br>
```

which produces:

> First line
>
> ---